# Stormpath - How to do a login by code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, stormpath

I'm learning Stormpath with Spring-Boot and Spring-Security. I want to do a Service to do the login of users, and I saw only examples by the login view of Stormpath's web, with the inputs of the email and password, but I want to do that by code, using the classes of Stormpath. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the code in Stormpath's [LoginController](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/blob/master/extensions/servlet/src/main/java/com/stormpath/sdk/servlet/mvc/LoginController.java#L243) and see how to do it manually. However, I'm not sure why you'd want to do that when Stormpath provides the integration so you hardly need to write any code. With our next release (and Spring Boot 1.5), you won't need any code to integrate it with Spring Boot and Spring Security. Just drop in the dependency and it works!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Matt. I want to do a microservice where it can receive the email and password, then it does the login in Stormpath and then it return a token, to share it to others microservices. But I only saw examples with the login view, like this example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-spring-boot-app-with-user-authentication.
.

Comment: You can make a POST to `/oauth/token` with `grant_type=password` and the username/password. For example, with HTTPie: `http --form POST localhost:8080/oauth/token grant_type='password' username='XXX' password='XXX'`. That'll return an access_token you can use to send in an Authorization header. For example: `http localhost:8080/my-api 'Authorization:Bearer <access_token>'`

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I tried a post with Postman: https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/8gQBBR479UJX4Aln2FZiS/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=passpass
And the response was: `{
  "status": 401,
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Authentication required.",
  "developerMessage": "Authentication with a valid API Key is required.",
  "moreInfo": "http://www.stormpath.com/docs/quickstart/connect",
  "requestId": "ce1c7ce0-e36e-11e6-a949-22000b4f80e1"
}`

I downloaded the apiKey.properties, and the Application has the api key.

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You should be hitting your Spring Boot app that has Stormpath integrated, not the API directly.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I did that, and when I do the post 

localhost:9999/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=useruse&password=passpass

`{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Unauthorized request Origin."
}`

I use application/x-www-form-urlencoded in Postman and I exported STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID and STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET. I dont know what is the problem.

Comment: I believe this is because Postman sends an Origin header and you don't have your server setup for CORS and accepting this Origin. Add the following to `src/main/resources/application.properties` should do the trick:

`stormpath.web.cors.allowed.originUris = chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop`

Or 

`stormpath.web.cors.allowed.originUris = *`

Comment: Thanks @Matt,  I tried without modifying the file application.properties, using **curl** like this: `curl -X POST \
  -H "Origin: http://localhost:9999" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d "grant_type=password&username=useruser&password=passpass" \
http://localhost:9999/oauth/token` and I got the access_token correctly. But when I use PostMan, i got the invalid_client error. Do you know what is the difference? In PostMan I set the header too, with Origin and Content-Type.

Comment: If you set `stormpath.web.cors.allowed.originUris = *`, I bet it will work in Postman. You can use something like https://www.charlesproxy.com/ to see what Origin header is being sent from Postman.

Comment: Thank you for all your help @Matt! :D